# Jumping up a View Controller Chain

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller chain that looks like this:

```
>ROOT (Login)
---->Main Menu
-------->Settings
```

Inside `Settings`, I have an option to log out. Is there a way to jump straight from `Settings` to `Login` in one smooth animation? Right now I'm calling `self.dismissViewController` on `Settings` and then on `Main Menu` which works, but shows two animations.

I'm looking for a way to transition directly from `Settings` to `Login`, so it shouldn't even show `Main Menu` on the way. Is this possible?

Comment: Change rootViewController on window.

Comment: So are you saying to instantiate a new Login View Controller and set it as the root view of the window?

Comment: i was always instantiating new login controller, look in github how people do that, it looks like this is the way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Inside AppDelegate (within didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) :-

```
   let userLoginStatus = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")


    if(userLoginStatus)
        {
// Assuming "Main" is the name of your storyboard
     let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       letMainVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") as! MainVC


               window!.rootViewController = letMainVC
               window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

In LoginVC after validating user credentials, when login is successful, set Bool value to true as follows:-

```
// after successful login 
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Similarly, when user clicks on logout set Bool to false and also set Login as Root VC as follows :-

```
//Inside logout closure :-

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


    let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login") as! LoginVC

    let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    appDel.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
```

This will make the transition directly in one go. Let me know in case of any issues.

**Note:-** Don't forget to setup Storyboard ID in Identity section of your Storyboard file.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the `self.dismissViewController` on Settings and on Main Menu, sending it only to the root.  The dismiss will dismiss (with animation if set to YES) everything presented on the receiver, including intermediates.

See [discussion section, second paragraph, in the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:).